# Angular - Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11 project, I have this code in the authentication service:

```js
login(data: {
  username: string;password: string;rememberMe: boolean
}): Observable < any > {
  const {
    username,
    password,
    rememberMe
  } = data;
  const loginData: OauthInterface = {
    ['grant_type']: PASSPORT_CLIENT.grantType,
    ['client_id']: PASSPORT_CLIENT.clientId,
    ['client_secret']: PASSPORT_CLIENT.clientSecret,
    username,
    password,
    scope: '',
  };
  //  const url = `oauth/token`;
  const url = `${API_URL}/oauth/token`;

  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
  };

  return this.http.post < any > (url, loginData, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      tap(user => rememberMe ? localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user)) : ''),
      tap(user => !rememberMe ? sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user)) : ''),
      tap(user => this.currentUserSubject.next(user)),
      tap(user => this.currentUserSubject.next(user)),
      this.currentUserDetails().subscribe(),
      catchError(error => throwError(error))
    );
}

currentUserDetails(): Observable < any > {
  const url = `${API_URL}/api/user`;
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
  };
  return this.http.get < any > (url, httpOptions)
    .pipe(map(user => {
        this.store.dispatch({
          type: '[APP STATE] set logged in user',
          payload: user
        });
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);

        return user;
      },
      () => {
        // Error Has been captured by interceptor
      }

    ));
}
```

I got this error:

> Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
> Type 'Subscription' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'

This line is highlighted:

> this.currentUserDetails().subscribe(),

How do I get it reolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick unblock, change:

```
this.currentUserDetails().subscribe(),
```

to:

```
tap(_ => this.currentUserDetails().subscribe()),
```

You can only put operators in a pipe and not a function call.